# Neopixel sample code crashing when using a higher number of pixels

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, neopixel

## Context

I'm restarting a personal project that involved an [ESP8266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010N1SPRK) and WS2812Bs (Neopixels).

It is worth noting that I do not have any Neopixels hooked up at the moment; I'm simply trying to get a feel for how fast I can update the pixels.

I'm running a very simple piece of example code taken from Adafruit's Neopixel GitHub repo. I've modified it slightly to make it more accurate to my use case and to remove comments (for the sake of posting here).

## Details

The sample code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 13        
#define NUMPIXELS 300 
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);  
  pixels.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Start");
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(i);
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0));
    pixels.show();
  }
  Serial.println("End");
}
```

It will crash before "End" is called. The loop only gets to ~227:

```
...
227

Soft WDT reset

ctx: cont 
sp: 3ffffd80 end: 3fffffd0 offset: 01b0

>>>stack>>>
3fffff30:  feefef00 feefeffe feefeffe 0000012c  
3fffff40:  3ffee798 00000003 3ffee798 40202a7c  
3fffff50:  3ffee798 3ffee768 3ffee798 40202bc5  
3fffff60:  3ffe894c 000000e3 3ffee798 40202cd7  
3fffff70:  3ffe8940 3ffee810 3ffee798 40202be0  
3fffff80:  3ffee798 3ffee768 0000012b 3ffee768  
3fffff90:  402014f2 3ffee768 000000e4 40202777  
3fffffa0:  feefeffe 00000000 3ffee7b4 3ffee7bc  
3fffffb0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee7b4 40202ed4  
3fffffc0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe85d8 40100739  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)
```

## Troubleshooting

This code will not crash if I reduce the number of pixels to 200 or add a delay(1) within the for loop.

Alternatively - removing the for loop and setting the LEDs by simply using the loop() seems to work.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 13        
#define NUMPIXELS 300 
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);  
  pixels.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println(i);
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0)); 
    pixels.show();

  if (i == 299) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i = i + 1;
  }
}
```

So - the issue seems to ultimately depend on calling show() a certain number of times (227+) within a for loop inside of the loop() function.

## Question

Many examples include the show within the for loop. I suspect that moving the show outside of the for loop is an adequate workaround; I did this in my original project with seemingly no issue.

But I'm still curious WHY this is happening. The fact that so many examples have the show() included in the for loop makes me think that this should work.

Does anybody know why setting ~300 LEDs in the above code would cause a crash, but 200 wouldn't?

Comment: Don’t `show` in the tight loop; only at the end.

Comment: Relevant article: https://www.weigu.lu/microcontroller/tips_tricks/watchdog_tips_tricks/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from the board indicates the problem:

```
Soft WDT reset
```

The software watchdog timer is kicking in and resetting the board. See https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/a02-my-esp-crashes.html#watchdog.

Embedded systems typically have a hardware and/or software watchdog. The watchdog will reset the system if it is not serviced within a predefined time period. This prevents the system becoming unresponsive if the software locks up or becomes overloaded.

For the `loop()` code in question:

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Start");
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(i);
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0));
    pixels.show();
  }
  Serial.println("End");
}
```

The implementation of `pixels.show()` uses a busy loop to implement the timing for writing to the LED. See https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/Adafruit_NeoPixel.cpp#L205:

```
  // Data latch = 300+ microsecond pause in the output stream. Rather than
  // put a delay at the end of the function, the ending time is noted and
  // the function will simply hold off (if needed) on issuing the
  // subsequent round of data until the latch time has elapsed. This
  // allows the mainline code to start generating the next frame of data
  // rather than stalling for the latch.
  while(!canShow());
```

227 iterations of the loop is enough of a busy loop to cause the watchdog timer to kick in.

Calling `pixels.show()` fewer times or `delay()` (which calls `yield()` internally) allows the watchdog timer to be serviced.

The simplest solution is to call `pixels.show()` once at the end of `loop()`.

So you need to remember to pat the puppy/dog - otherwise it bites.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll do some more reading into the watchdog timer. I might try disabling it to test the performance difference between show() in and out of the for loop; I will ultimately re-enable it and just include it out of the loop though. It does surprise me that a fast(ish), finite loop would trigger the watchdog though. I be more mindful of the puppy in the future and give it plenty of pats!

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but these strips work in a serial way: the first LED is taking the first 24bits, ditch them and pass the remaining to the following LED and so on. That does mean the message you are sending is increasing with the number of the LEDs you are **currently** addressing.

These LEDs IC also need some time to reset before the next message is received, it is possible that there is a data conflict as the strip cannot catch up with an increasing signal length at full speed of you ESP.

Your second example contains some tests, which might slow down the transfer enough to avoid the conflict.

So, you might just need to add a small delay in your first example, from the [documentation](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) something as small as 50 microsecs might be enough. You can use [`delayMicrosecond()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delaymicroseconds/) for that.

Comment: Yeah - I've looked at DotStars for this reason. They have their own timing controllers on the LED, so you can allegedly update them faster. But, I met somebody who has done a much larger project with Neopixels and he didn't have the same performance problems. I'll switch if needed - but it seems likely that I was doing something inefficiently. Anyways - I did try a 50 micro delay, but that was too short. I think I could find the sweet spot by trial and error, but I'm probably going to opt to just moving the show() function as I'd rather not introduce unnecessary delay.

Comment: Seems a good way to go if you do not actually want that your LEDs shine up one after another for some reason!

Comment: Actually, from @Ben T 's answer, that is weird… Even a 50 micro delay should trig the `yield()` function and thus reset the watchdod.

Comment: In the Adafruit Neopixel code there is a comment above the show function that states that the function causes the timing to get out of sync by about 30 microseconds per pixel. Perhaps that is also screwing up the watchdog? I'll update my post if I learn more this weekend.